# Find String and Replace with SUBSTRING

Tags: text-processing, command-line

I have the file like this. ex.(test.txt)

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE=CA AZ
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

All I need to do is replace this `$$STATE=CA AZ` with first TWO bytes of this value.
i.e(`CA`).

The output file should be

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE=CA
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

Comment: Hi! What have you tried this far, and where in that process are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming that these couples of character after `STATE` are in capital. If not then you should replace `[A-Z]` `[A-Za-z]`.

You can use this simple command:

```
sed -Ei 's/^\$\$STATE=([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{2})/\$\$STATE=\1/g' sed_file
```

It will match with lines starting with `$$` like `$$STATE=AB CD` and will replace them with `$$STATE` and first subexpression `\1`.

Edit: If you want an extra single quote then use:

```
sed -Ei 's/^\$\$STATE=([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{2})/\$\$STATE='"'"'\1'"'"'/g' sed_file
```

Comment: perhaps also anchoring to the beginning of line and including the `$$`?

Comment: well, thanks but it should not make any change.

Comment: Unless they had other lines with values containing "STATE="

Comment: I also want to append single quotes to this value. So it should be like $$STATE='CA'

Comment: Yadhav - Can you please help me on the additional question. Thanks! I also want to append single quotes to this value. So it should be like $$STATE='CA'

Comment: @VelavaShanmugam wait I am working on it.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I am stuck in the second problem OP asked, can you give hint how to add single quote?

Comment: I think it should be asked and answered as a new, separate question.

Comment: @VelavaShanmugam edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="=" } $1 == "$$STATE" { split($2,a," "); $2 = "'"'"'" a[1] "'"'"'" } 1' file
```

This uses `awk` to parse the file as a collection of `=`-delimited fields.  If the first field is the exact string `$$STATE`, then the second field is split on spaces and assigned the value of its first space-delimited bit, with single quotes around it.

The funky looking `"'"'"'"` is a double quoted single quote character within a single quoted `awk` script.

The result would be

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE='CA'
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

Alternatively, with `sed`:

```
sed -E '/^\$\$STATE=/s/=([^ ]*).*/='"'"'\1'"'"'/' file
```

This would locate any line that starts with the string `$$STATE=` and then replace anything after the `=` with the first bit before a space, again with single quotes inserted.