# Replace text using sed and also add single quote to it

Tags: text-processing, sed

I answered [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495470/255251), but I am stuck on the part where I have to add a single quote also to it.

Like original file is:

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE=CA AZ
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

New file should be:

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE='CA'
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

I used

```
sed -Ei 's/^\$\$STATE=([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{2})/\$\$STATE=\1/g' sed_file
```

So I got:

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE=CA
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

but now I am unable to add single quote in it. I tried escaping, used double quotes instead of single quotes, tried without quotes, but none is working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two options:

Temporarily break out of the single quoted string that is the `sed` expression, insert `"'"` (a quoted single quote character) and continue.  Repeat for the other quote.

```
$ sed -E 's/^\$\$STATE=([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{2})/$$STATE='"'"'\1'"'"'/' file
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE='CA'
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

Note that `$` does not have to be escaped in the replacement string.

You could also use `\'` in place of `"'"`:

```
$ sed -E 's/^\$\$STATE=([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{2})/$$STATE='\''\1'\''/' file
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE='CA'
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

or,

Use double quotes around the expression and single quotes as ordinary characters within. This requires that all existing backslashes and `$` characters are protected from the shell.

```
$ sed -E "s/^\\\$\\\$STATE=([A-Z]{2}) ([A-Z]{2})/\$\$STATE='\1'/" file
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE='CA'
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/2017
```

The excessive escaping here is needed because you want `sed` to get the literal string `\$` in the regular expression (and just `$` in the replacement part).  Within double quotes in the shell, `\$` is just a literal `$`.  `\\$` would be a literal backslash followed by `$`, and the shell would try to use whatever is after the `$` as something to expand (`$$` or `$STATE` for example).  Using `\\\$`, we give a literal backslash followed by a literal `$`.

I've also removed the `g` at the end of the `sed` expression.  Since you are anchoring it at the beginning of the line, we don't expect the substitution to be performed more than a single time.

Comment: Can you explain the second one why this much escaping is needed?

Comment: @P_Yadav See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, you can use the following to substitute plus slip in single quotes from a `bash` commandline `sed` invocation as shown :

```
 $   sed -e 's/$$STATE=\([A-Z][A-Z]\) [A-Z][A-Z]$/$$STATE='"'\1'/" sed_file
```

This way you are saved from the "excessive backslashing", known to cause 'backslashitis'.

A few points to ponder:

1. The `$` loses it's metacharacter status when used any place except the last, on the lhs of s/// command. Ofc, you must be in single quotes otw anyway the bash will kick in nd expand vars. Im talking of what sed does.
2. In the rhs of the s/// command, the $ is not a metacharacter, so no need to escape it.
3. Sed is to be in -e mode not -re mode.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

I Have tried with below method

```
sed "/^\$\$STATE/s/ .*/'/g" filename| sed "/\$\$STATE/s/=/&'/g"
```

output

```
$$BATCHCTRL=TEST-012017
$$STATE='CA'
$$FROM_DATE=01/10/2017
$$TO_DATE=01/30/201
```

Comment: Can you explain the second one, how does `/s/=/&'/` works?

Comment: & has special meaning in sed. if you want replace = with =, instead of using s/=/=,/ You can use s/=/&,/ That mean with the exsisting content we can add new things which you want to add

Comment: Welcome P_Yadav